# Programmatically All Ansible Task attributes

Tags: python, ansible, reverse-engineering

All play attributes was answered

```
python -c 'import ansible.playbook.play as P; print P.Play()._valid_attrs.keys()'
```

But struggling to retrieve **Task attributes** in the same way.

The following snippet does not return anything :

```
python -c 'import ansible.playbook.task as T ; T.Task()._valid_attrs;'
```

I am relying to [this code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/task.py) to do this reverse engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `print` method :

```
python -c 'import ansible.playbook.task as T ; print T.Task()._valid_attrs.keys();'
```